# Angular 5 - JSON to "scope" binding to *NgFor

Tags: arrays, json, angular, rest, angular5

I want to bind the data that i get from my JSON request to the *NgFor to be able to read it out, This is how the data looks like that i get in:

```
{Id: null, Code: "9348892084", HasInfo: true, Info: Array(26)}
HasInfo:true
Info:
Array(26)
0:{ProductId: 32631, Name: "JNOOS", Image: "http://sd-m-mg", …}
1:{ProductId: 32969, Name: "SWIFT", Image: "http://sd-33087.jpg",…}
2:{ProductId: 32570, Name: "GABIX", Image: "http://sd-c7273.jpg", …}
3:{ProductId: 32473, Name: "MISMA", Image: "http://sd-mt8-8343e4d95.jpg", …}
```

I was working with AngularJS before and there i made the request as such:

```
$scope.getAll{

    $http({
        method: 'Get',
        url: "http://URL/" + Code
        })
        .success(function (data) {
           $scope.All = data.Info;
        })
```

No i am moving to Angular5 and i would like to get the same array of information bind to the :

```
<div *ngFor="let x of info">
    {{ x.Name }}
</div>
```

How would i adjust the below to get the same as above?

```
export class AppComponent {

  readonly ROOT_URL = 'http://url/content/'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getData()
}

getData() {
  this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL + 'Getscope')
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        var test = data;   
        // var info = data.Info = not valid!;  
        // var test can't be approached by *ngFor
        console.log(test);
        console.log(test.info);

        //$scope.info = data.Info;
        //this.info = data;
      }, error => {
        console.error("HTTP FAILURE ERROR!!!");
      }
    )
 };
}
```

Also the json output has an array inside an object, do i say this correct?

Comment: What's the log of test ?

Comment: declare test globally as test array and use this.test = data also please share what is the console for test in get method

Comment: the console just outputs the result above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code you are using `info` in `html` **but not assigning to any class variable**,

Take a public variable  `public info;` and assign data using **`this.info = data.Info`**

**Component:**

```
export class AppComponent {

  readonly ROOT_URL = 'http://url/content/'
  public info;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getData()
}

getData() {
  this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL + 'Getscope')
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.info = data['Info']; // here is the change
      }, error => {
        console.error("HTTP FAILURE ERROR!!!");
      }
    )
 };
}
```

**Your HTML can be same:**

```
<div *ngFor="let x of info">
    {{ x.Name }}
</div>
```

Comment: the this.info = data.info; is not allowed for the second part (data.info;) it mentions [ts] Property Info does not exist on type Óbject'

Comment: console.log(data.info\)

Comment: @EwaldBos, `info` is `capital case`, change it to, `data.Info`

Comment: the problem is with the data.Info not the this.info, the 'Info' is red underlined and has this message attached to it "[ts] Property 'Info' does not exist on type 'Object'"

Comment: what returns when you `console.log(data)`

Comment: You can also try, `this.info = data['Info'];`

Comment: Yes this: " this.info = data['Info']; " worked in combination with the public variable! Thank you so much :) you made my day

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use an async pipe. This way you do not need to subscribe to the stream returned by `http.get`.

app.component.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AppComponent {
  readonly url = 'http://url/content/'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  info$: Observable<any[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.info$ = this.http.get(this.url + 'Getscope')
      .pipe(map(resp => resp.Info));
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let x of info$ | async">
    {{ x.Name }}
</div>
```